# vlc in android studio with ffmpeg in linux

Tags: android, ffmpeg, vlc

I am using VLC in android studio with FFMPEG in Linux, I need to change some code in FFMPEG c file but when I compile FFMPEG and run VLC application in android it uses the original version of FFMPEG and not the modified

my compile code is:

```
./configue
sudo make install
make
```

I have tried everything 
Why has this occurred? Maybe there is another way to compile or how to find the source of FFMPEG if I delete the file of FFMPEG and compile it restore the FFMPEG file from somewhere? However I don't know how?

Comment: You can't just compile a static FFmpeg and expect other, existing programs that depend on it to just use it. I know nothing of Android, but your VLC may be linked to the (shared?) FFmpeg files in `/usr/`, but your files are probably in `/usr/local/`, and anyway VLC may only work with a certain FFmpeg version. Long story short, you'll probably need to compile VLC too and tell it where the FFmpeg files are that you want it to link to.

Comment: so where can i change the position of my ffmpeg location?

Comment: You probably don't need to. You can tell the VLC you compile where dependencies are with `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

i find on the net the same problem and the solution.
1. remove the .ffmpeg file to force rebuild

2. modify vlc/extras/package/ios/build.sh to remove the line "make fetch" which will NOT download anything from vlc github root
3. modify buildMobileVLCKit.sh to remove the line: git reset --hard ${TESTEDHASH} git am ../../patches/*.patch to NOT force update the build.sh.
4. package the source code and save it as vlc/contrib/tarballs/ffmpeg-HEAD.tar.gz
5. run the build sh ./buildMobileVLCKit.sh -d -s -v from VLCKit
   That will make sure it's copying the right ffmpeg source(not the version from github), and compile and link properly.

   It is for iphone i need in android can someone help me with it??